# Tikz Diagram in align environment with picture nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to reproduce an image. I could probably do alone but it may not be the best way so I am asking what is the fastest and easiest way  achieve the result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\newcommand{\der}[2]{\dfrac{d#1}{d#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$\begin{aligned}[t]
     &\phantom{==}\der{}{x} (x^{2} \cdot x^{5}) \\ \\
             &=x^{2} \cdot \textcolor{red}{5x^{4}}+x^{5} \cdot 
 \textcolor{red}{2x}\\
             &=5x^{6}+2x^{6}\\
             &=7x^{6}
\end{aligned}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proposal. It requires the latest version of tikzmark, i.e. should work if you have updated your TeX installation in the past 2 months or so.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\der}[2]{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$\begin{aligned}[t]
     &\phantom{==}\der{}{x} (x^{2} \tikzmarknode{0}{\cdot} x^{5}) \\[0.8cm]
             &=\tikzmarknode{1}{x^{2}} \cdot 
             \tikzmarknode[red]{2}{5x^{4}}+
             \tikzmarknode{3}{x^{5}} \tikzmarknode{5}{\cdot}
\tikzmarknode[red]{4}{2x}\\
             &=5x^{6}+2x^{6}\\
             &=7x^{6}
\end{aligned}$
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,cyan!70]
\path ([yshift=0.1cm]1.north) coordinate (aux);
\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw   (\X |-aux) node[above,circle,draw,font=\small,inner sep=1pt]
(L\X){\X};}
\draw[very thick] ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=2pt]L1.west) |- 
([xshift=2pt,yshift=8pt]L4.east) coordinate (aux2) -- ([xshift=2pt]L4.east);
\draw[very thick,-latex] (0.south) -- (0|-aux2);
\path ([yshift=-4pt]5.south) node[below,circle,draw,font=\small,inner
sep=1pt]{5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or (it is hard for me to judge where the `5` node should be sitting)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
\newcommand{\der}[2]{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$\begin{aligned}[t]
     &\phantom{==}\der{}{x} (x^{2} \tikzmarknode{0}{\cdot} x^{5}) \\[0.8cm]
             &=\tikzmarknode{1}{x^{2}} \cdot 
             \tikzmarknode[red]{2}{5x^{4}}+
             \tikzmarknode{3}{x^{5}} \cdot
\tikzmarknode[red]{4}{2x}\\
             &=5x^{6}+\tikzmarknode{5}{2x^{6}}\\
             &=7x^{6}
\end{aligned}$
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,cyan!70]
\path ([yshift=0.1cm]1.north) coordinate (aux);
\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw   (\X |-aux) node[above,circle,draw,font=\small,inner sep=1pt]
(L\X){\X};}
\draw[very thick] ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=2pt]L1.west) |- 
([xshift=2pt,yshift=8pt]L4.east) coordinate (aux2) -- ([xshift=2pt]L4.east);
\draw[very thick,-latex] (0.south) -- (0|-aux2);
\node[right=3pt of 5,circle,draw,font=\small,inner sep=1pt]{5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was just going  to post this small issue. Thanks Marmot. This is very helpful!

Comment: Every student knows (or should know) that is the same, but I'd swap `2x` and `x^5`... lol

Comment: @Sigur Yes, thanks for the heads up. I guess that's the OP's decision. ;-)